# How to dynamically write the query in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to write the dynamically the below query?

Table

```
empid       designation       interestes
1           developer,tester      cricket,chess
1           developer             chess
1           techlead              cricket
```

Condition:

```
IF empid = 1
AND (designation LIKE '%developer%' OR designationLIKE '%techlead%') 
OR (interests LIKE '%cricket%').
```

How to write the above query dynamically if designations need to send more than 2,and also same on interstes .

please tell me ...

EDIT stored procedure code:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetDevices]
    @id INT,
    @designation NVARCHAR (MAX)
 AS
 BEGIN
    declare @idsplat varchar(MAX)
    set @idsplat = @UserIds
        create table #u1 (id1 varchar(MAX))
        set @idsplat = 'insert #u1 select ' + replace(@idsplat, ',', ' union select ')
        exec(@idsplat)
      Select 
        id FROM dbo.DevicesList WHERE id=@id  AND designation IN (select id1 from #u1)
      END
```

Comment: Please make your question clearer.  Do you want to write dynamic SQL?

Comment: i placed the all designations like checkboxes in UI.users selects no.of designations like developer,tester,projectlead,techlead dynamically coming to query.How to query to  get related records from DB...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970877/how-to-dynamically-write-the-query-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

Then when your form is submitted, create a string of designations (should really be a list of foreign keys if you have a 1 to many relationship) and pass that to the SQL.  Then parse it into a table using one of many [open-source SQL user functions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str):

```
-- @designations = 'developer,tester,techlead'

select text_val 
from dbo.fn_ParseText2Table(@designations,',')

/* results:

text_val 
--------
developer
tester
techlead

*/
```

Once you have the values in a table you can do any standard join or query operations.

Comment: Hi @Terry Thanks.But i am getting exact matching records.i.e if i send  id=1 and designation="'developer'" getting only 2nd record.but 1st record also developer designation it was wrong.by using like getting all developer records but i am not able to send multiple parameter like id=1,designation="'%developer%','%tester%','%techlead%'" getting error as "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.".please check my SP...